# Entering sudo password through c

Tags: c, linux, sudo

I asked this question before but no-one gave a straight answer. I wanted to know how I can enter the sudo password through c code. I'm trying to write a script to be able to execute sudo bash and enter the password required. Also I know the risks of hardcoding passwords but I don't mind in this instance.

Comment: you need to write the script for that. For e.g `read passwd`. If you written any script then add in the question, we can help it out.

Comment: The password is just a string. Prompt the user and read it from `stdin`. Otherwise you should provide details of your actual problem, show the relevant code, and clearly state where you are having trouble.

Comment: Agree with @jww This may be an [XY Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).  IANAE, being a mostly Windows guru, but I'd look at using the setuid(2) call in the program to set the uid to root, then using chown to make it owned by root, and setting the "setuid" bit on it with chmod.  I'd just get input from a linux expert first, I might have missed something, or got something wrong here.

Comment: @dgnuff: if the executable is owned by root and has the setuid bit set, then it will run as root; there is no need (or point) in calling `setuid`.

Comment: I'm not really sure on how to start so I don't actually have a program but any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

No. Doing it that way is an [antipattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-pattern).

There are several alternatives to choose from, depending on the situation:

- Use [gksudo](https://linux.die.net/man/1/gksudo) (if `DISPLAY` environment variable is set) for a graphical prompt.
- Install the scripts to be executed in `/usr/share/yourapp/scripts/` or `/usr/lib/yourapp/scripts/`, and the proper sudo configuration that allows running them with sudo without supplying a password in `/etc/sudoers.d/yourapp` (or `/etc/sudoers` in systems without `/etc/sudoers.d/`)
- At the beginning of your program, check if `geteuid() == 0`. If not, re-execute self using gksudo/sudo, to obtain root privileges.

  For normal operations, your program should use only the privileges of the real user who executed the program. To be able to raise the privileges later, the root privileges are "saved". So, initially, your program will drop the privileges using e.g.

  ```
      uid_t  uid = getuid();
      gid_t  gid = getgid();
      if (setresgid(gid, gid, 0) == -1 ||
          setresuid(uid, uid, 0) == -1) {
          /* Failed: no root privileges! */
      }
  ```

  To re-elevate privileges, you use

  ```
      if (setresgid(gid, 0, 0) == -1 ||
          setresuid(uid, 0, 0) == -1) {
          /* Failed: no root privileges! */ 
      }
  ```

  which changes only the effective identity to root (as setuid binaries do), or

  ```
      if (setresgid(0, 0, 0) == -1 ||
          setresuid(0, 0, 0) == -1) {
          /* Failed: no root privileges! */ 
      }
  ```

  which changes both real and effective identity to root.

  Often, the privileges are elevated for only forking a privileged child slave, after which the main program drops the privileges completely using

  ```
      if (setresgid(gid, gid, gid) == -1 ||
          setresuid(uid, uid, uid) == -1) {
          /* Failed. */
      }
  ```

  keeping just a socket pair or pipes between the parent and the child; the child can then fork and execute new processes. (If an Unix domain socket is used, the parent can even send new descriptors to be used for the new processes' standard streams via ancillary messages.)
- Use filesystem capabilities to give your program the capabilities it needs, without elevating all its privileges.

  For example, [`sudo setcap CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE=pe /usr/bin/yourapp`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/setcap.8.html) gives `/usr/bin/yourapp` the CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE capability (permitted and effective; not inherited), which allows your program to bind to any unused TCP/IP and UDP/IP ports, including 1-1024. See [man 7 capabilities](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/capabilities.7.html) for detailed descriptions of the capabilities.
- Use a trusted helper binary (program) to act as sudo for you. If you install this at e.g. `/usr/lib/yourapp/execute`, you can add the sudo configuration necessary to allow executing it without supplying a password. Alternatively, you can make it setuid root, or give it the necessary capabilities via filesystem capabilities.

  To avoid other programs from exploiting this helper, you must ensure it is only executed by your program. One way to ensure that is to have your program create an Unix domain socket pair, leaving one end open in your program, and the other end for the helper in e.g. descriptor 3. Before doing anything, the helper checks that there is nothing to receive yet (to avoid "pipe stuffing" attacks), and writes a single byte to the parent. The parent responds with a single byte, but with its credentials in an [ancillary message](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/cmsg.3.html). The credentials contain the process ID of the parent. (Do not simply use `getppid()`, because that allows certain attacks; this socket approach verifies the parent is still alive when we do the check.) Finally, use [`readlink()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/readlink.2.html) to read the `/proc/PID/exe` pseudo-symlink, where PID is the parent process ID from the credentials ancillary message. At this point, the helper should send a byte, and receive a byte with the credentials again as an ancillary message, to ensure the parent process is still the same.

  The verification process is complex, but necessary, to avoid making it easy to exploit root privileges by misusing the helper. For another approach to do exactly this, look into [Apache suEXEC](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/suexec.html), the helper used by Apache to execute CGI programs with specific user privileges.

---

Let's say you are totally uninterested in doing things in a sensible way, and insist on using passwords.  Fine; all I ask is that you don't publish such code, or at least warn your users that it is completely unsafe.

This is not just a crude hack: it is a suicidal one, similar to putting the password to your web site in your e-mail signature, because you only mail to friends who should have admin access to your site in the first place.  So, footgun, with a hair trigger, no safety, and armed with buckshot coated in tetrodotoxin. With a nice label with big, child-readable letters saying "Please play with me! I'm safe!", stored in the kids bedroom.

The simplest thing to do is to execute `sudo` with the `-S` flag, which causes it to read the password from the standard input. For example, **example.c**:

```
#define  _POSIX_C_SOURCE  200809L
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main(void)
{
    FILE  *cmd;
    int    status;

    cmd = popen("/usr/bin/sudo -S id -un 2>/dev/null", "w");
    if (!cmd) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot run sudo: %s.\n", strerror(errno));
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    fprintf(cmd, "Password\n");
    fflush(cmd);

    status = pclose(cmd);
    if (WIFEXITED(status)) {
        if (WEXITSTATUS(status) == EXIT_SUCCESS)
            fprintf(stderr, "No errors.\n");
        else
            fprintf(stderr, "Command failed with exit status %d.\n", WEXITSTATUS(status));
    } else
    if (WIFSIGNALED(status))
        fprintf(stderr, "Command killed by signal %d.\n", WTERMSIG(status));
    else
        fprintf(stderr, "Command failed.\n");

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

The command pipe is opened in write mode, so that we can write the password to it. The `2>/dev/null` redirection hides the password prompt.

If the password is correct, the above will output what `id -un` outputs when run as root (i.e.: `root`) to standard output, and `No errors.` to standard error.

If the password is incorrect, sudo will retry a couple of times (so nothing will happen for a few seconds), then the program will report `Command failed with exit status 1.` to standard error, because that's what `sudo` does when the password is incorrect.